# Using global style to define underlineColorAndroid prop

Tags: react-native

I have a file that I am using to define global styles. I would like to define a const within the file to use for the underlineColorAndroid prop.

My global stylesheet looks like this:

```
const React = require('react-native')

const { StyleSheet } = React

const underlineColorAndroid = '#F86C51'

module.exports = StyleSheet.create({

  background: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },

})
```

I import the file like this:

```
import globalStyles from '../styles/global'
```

And I use the style within the prop like this:

```
underlineColorAndroid={globalStyles.underlineColorAndroid}
```

This doesn't work, any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `module.exports` syntax, you can use the [ES6 `export` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) to define both default and named exports:

```
export const underlineColorAndroid = '#F86C51'

export default StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
})
```

The default export can be imported as before:

```
import globalStyles from '../styles/global';
```

The named exports can be imported using curly braces to denote destructuring:

```
import { underlineColorAndroid } from '../styles/global';
```

Or both at the same time:

```
import globalStyles, { underlineColorAndroid } from '../styles/global';
```

However, it might be better to split the style sheet and the named variables into different files for clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Worked like a charm.